# Django REST Framework filter multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

> Models

```
class Task(Model):
    employee_owner = ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=CASCADE)
    employee_doer = ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=CASCADE)
```

> Views

```
class TaskViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    filter_class = TaskFilter
```

> Filter

```
class TaskFilter(FilterSet):
    owner_id = NumberFilter(name='employee_owner__id')
    doer_id = NumberFilter(name='employee_doer__id')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = {
            'owner_id',
            'doer_id'
        }
```

> Endpoints

```
http://localhost:8000/api/tasks?owner_id=1&doer_id=1
```

*(Gives only those tasks where `owner` and `doer` are the same employee)*

```
http://localhost:8000/api/tasks?owner_id=1
```

*(Gives only those tasks where `owner` is specific employee and `doer` is anyone)*

```
http://localhost:8000/api/tasks?doer_id=1
```

*(Gives only those tasks where `doer` is specific employee and `owner` is anyone)*

> What I want

I want an endpoint like:

```
http://localhost:8000/api/tasks?both_id=1
```

*(Which would give me all results from above 3 endpoints)*

I want `django-filter` to do filtering exactly like:

```
Task.objects.filter(
    Q(employee_owner__id=1) | Q(employee_doer__id=1)
)
```

How can I achieve that ? Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can customize filter using [`method`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/ref/filters.html#method) argument like this:

```
class TaskFilter(FilterSet):
    owner_id = NumberFilter(name='employee_owner__id')
    doer_id = NumberFilter(name='employee_doer__id')
    both_id = NumberFilter(method='filter_both')

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = {
            'owner_id',
            'doer_id',
            'both_id' 
        }

    def filter_both(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(
            Q(employee_owner__id=value) | Q(employee_doer__id=value)
        )
```

Comment: Perfect answer from neverwalkaloner as usual :)

Comment: You have a `Q()` in there, but neither your answer or the docs linked seem to explain where it is imported from or what it represents.

Comment: Ah, found it finally with the right search against `model.objects.filter` - it's `from django.db.models import Q`

Comment: I have a similar case and for me this doesn't work as `both_id` is not a field within the `Task` model (if I understood the question correctly). The provided solution returns `'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: both_id`

Answer (score 5):

Personally I would like to suggest use DjangoFilterBackend for filtration

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
```

After that

```
class TaskViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    queryset = Task.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ['owner_id', 'doer_id']# pass query through params
```